# Calculating the SUM of (quantity * price) from 2 different tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have following 2 tables,

**item_store**

[image: item_store table]

**purchase**

[image: purchase table]

Based on brand_id and purchase_time i want to calculate cummulative sale amount of items sold. 
In above sample scenario item '1' has been purchased 2 times from store '1' and once from store '2'.
The total sale amount should be total_quantity * price = (2 + 5) * 10 + 7 * 12 = 70 + 84 = 154.

I am finding it challenging to join 2 tables in such a way that price is taken from item_store and
cumulative quantity is taken from purchase table to calculate total amount.

These 2 tables need to be joined based on item_id and store_id and where clause should include
brand_id and purchase_time from purchase table (for example - where brand_id = 1 and purchase_time >= '2017-02-01 00:00:00.000'
and purchase_time <= '2017-02-10 00:00:00.000').

There is always going to be one-to-one mapping between item_id and brand_id as of now.

**EDIT:**

If instead of using quantity column in purchase table if i want to just use count of records found in purchase table to calculate total sale amount any idea how to achieve it. What i mean is suppose there is no quantity column in purchase table and instead every single entry in purchase table represents one item quantity sold. 
So something like: count(*) of records in purchase table * price in item_store

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you need. This just requires joining the tables.

```
select sum(p.quantity*i.price)
from purchase p
join item_store i on p.item_id=i.item_id and p.store_id=i.store_id
where p.brand_id = 1 
and p.purchase_time >= '2017-02-01 00:00:00.000' 
and p.purchase_time <= '2017-02-10 00:00:00.000'
```

Edit: Based on OP's update

```
select count(*) over(partition by p.item_id,p.store_id) * i.price 
from purchase p
join item_store i on p.item_id=i.item_id and p.store_id=i.store_id
where p.brand_id = 1 
and p.purchase_time >= '2017-02-01 00:00:00.000' 
and p.purchase_time <= '2017-02-10 00:00:00.000'
```

Comment: the purchase time for the other two records is outside of the date range specified.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, If instead of quantity i want to consider count of records present in purchase table for that brand_id, any idea how to achieve it.

Comment: do you mean `count(*) over() * i.price`?

Comment: I mean count(*) over p.quantity. Or count(*) instead of p.quantity

Comment: @ivish .. if you post it in the question..i can answer it

Comment: I think simply using - select sum(i.price) from purchase p ... in your query above should work.

Comment: but that wouldn't consider the number of rows if there are more than 1 for a given item_id and store_id

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first bit of the question:

```
SELECT sum(p.quantity * itm.price) as total
  FROM Item_Store itm
  JOIN Purchase p ON p.store_Id = itm.store_id
```

To move onto the second piece of the question where you talk about the tables having to use a where condition which is throwing your results off, you can simply use a nested select statement - then it makes no difference about the where condition affecting your results.

so you could have:

original select statement - something like:

```
Select 

column1, column2, etc..., 

(SELECT sum(p.quantity * itm.price) as total
  FROM Item_Store itm
  JOIN Purchase p ON p.store_Id = itm.store_id) as TotalSales

FROM item_store itm
JOIN purchase p ON p.store_Id = itm.store_id
Where brand_id = 1
AND (purchase_time >= '2017-02-01 00:00:00.000' and purchase_time <= '2017-02-10 00:00:00.000')
```

You could even do it as a in-line view join, which I would say is better as it'll be more effective in terms of performance i.e.

```
Select 

    column1, column2, TotalSales.total, etc...

    FROM item_store itm
    JOIN purchase p ON p.store_Id = itm.store_id
    JOIN (SELECT sum(p.quantity * itm.price) as total
          FROM Item_Store itm2
          JOIN Purchase p2 ON p2.store_Id = itm2.store_id) as TotalSales
    Where brand_id = 1
    AND (purchase_time >= '2017-02-01 00:00:00.000' and purchase_time <= '2017-02-10 00:00:00.000')
```

You'll get the same results, but the join version should be more efficient as it's not having to run the sql for every row returned.

Hope that makes sense!